# iMacros w EVAL([javascript]} FORMAT errors on attempts and no solution

Tags: javascript, syntax, format, imacros

Instead of a long list of port#s for the proxy address, I need to generate a port# in specific range on a continuous basis. Everything else  works just fine except the JS I wrote ...

```
     TAB T=1 
    TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
    CLEAR
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO 
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET ThisPort EVAL("var X = .........  X;")
PROMPT {{ThisPort}}
PAUSE
PROXY ADDRESS= 178.62.222.222:{{ThisPort}}
```

These are some of previous attempts .. tried to use JShint.com but as far as I get is FORMAT or SYNTAX errors.

No formal JS training, just usually do much better w iMacros  :(

```
'Error -1250: JScript statement in EVAL contains the following error: 
'Expected expression. 
'Line 12: SET ThisPort EVAL(" var X=( for (i = 3016; i <= 3065; i++)  { for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++); } X; ")
'Error -1250: JScript statement in EVAL contains the following error: 
'Variable 'i' has not been declared. 
'Line 12: SET ThisPort EVAL("  for (i = 3016; i <= 3065; i++)  { for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++); } ")
```

The reason I am not just using a list of variables is that I have no way to use same numbers more than once. ie used the 50 port numbers multiple times in list and all I get is a STOP after the first round of 50 ... gggrrr.. even restarting iMacros doesnt cure. The iMacros forum had only 1 real thread on the subject and the primary response was to use the list multiplying  :(

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
...
SET ThisPort EVAL("var X = ''; for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {for (i = 3016; i <= 3065; i++) X += ((X == '') ? '' : '[EXTRACT]') + i;} X;")
'PROMPT {{ThisPort}}
SET !EXTRACT {{ThisPort}}
...
```

Comment: ... Looking at the code I had high hopes .. running it in iMacros gives this error  `code` Error -1250: JScript statement in EVAL contains the following error: Variable 'j' has not been declared. Line 6: SET ThisPort EVAL `code`  ... Can you have another look at it please? ..  I updated the question to include the actual usage (not that it impairs JS at all ..

Comment: looks like there is a ' } '  missing ... I cant figure out where the ` '[EXTRACT]'  `  is actually into the processing  .. FWIW my working code for the (if ?  t : f ) on another macro works using this `SET TestPREV EVAL(" (('{{TheNowIP}}' === '{{ThePrevIP}}') ? 'yes' : 'no'); ")` that is without needing the 'x' at start or end of the formula. Tried to find an alternative solution without success ... Jon

Comment: I use ‘iMacros’ as an extension for Firefox and the code provided works without any problems. Taking into account the appearing error you may try to define the ‘i’ & ‘j’ variables explicitly, i.e.: `... SET ThisPort EVAL("var i; var j; var X = '';...`. And as to your last comment – see the wiki about the command ‘EVAL’.